# soup.find does not return anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to pull some information from an Amazon page. I've written these few basic lines, but they are not working.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Cooler-Master-SickleFlow-120-Radiators/dp/B0046U6DWO/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=green+case+fan&qid=1578069342&sr=8-3'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
print(price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all-right, but `html.parser` parses the page content badly. Use `html5lib` or `lxml` instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Cooler-Master-SickleFlow-120-Radiators/dp/B0046U6DWO/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=green+case+fan&qid=1578069342&sr=8-3'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')  # <-- use `html5lib` or `lxml`
price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString" id="priceblock_ourprice">$10.50</span>
```